# Converting a 1 second clock into a 0.1 second clock

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have an fpga board with a 50 MHz clock, and I have this function to convert the signals from that into a 1 second clock. I want to know what adjustments I should be making to get an output of 0.1 seconds rather than 1 second.

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity clk_gen is
port(
  clk_50M: in std_logic; 
  clk_1s: out std_logic
   );
end clk_gen;

architecture arch of clk_gen is
    signal p_reg: unsigned(31 downto 0);
    constant PHA: unsigned(31 downto 0):= x"00000056"; 

begin
   -- ddfs for 1-sec pulse (based on 50 MHz clk)
   process(clk_50M)
   begin
      if (clk_50M'event and clk_50M='1') then
         p_reg <= p_reg + PHA;
      end if;
   end process;
    clk_1s <= p_reg(31);
end arch;
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you understand the algorithm, i.e. what this code is doing? If yes, please explain it to me so I'm certain you do. Because if you do, you should be able to solve this yourself, and if you don't, you have a lot to learn. You cannot expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: I think your code doesn't do anything, because p_reg stays (others => 'U') for all the time ...
What you need is a strobe generator.

Answer (score 0):

A 50Mhz FPGA clock means there are 50,000,000 (50e6) clock edges in a second.

So if you want 1/10 of a second, simply divide your 50 Mhz clock by 10 to get the total number of clock edges which need to pass to obtain a .1 second delay.

> 50,000,000 / 10 = 5,000,000 clock edges

I am unsure what your VHDL does; there are no counters or changes to values...

To simply describe what should be done ...

```
process(50_Mhz)
begin
if rising_edge(50_Mhz) then
    if counter < 5000000 then
        counter <= counter + 1;
    else
        counter <= 0; -- when it get's here .1 seconds have passed
    end if;
end if;
```

Of course this is not complete. You must declare the variables appropriately and toggle the signals you desire after the 0.1 seconds have passed.